# Problems when migrating from Facebook SDK v5.4 to alpha v6

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the following code after I login, which worked on 5.4.1, but now it isn't working as expected.

```
FacebookOAuthResult pResult;
if (m_pClient.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out pResult))
{
  if (pResult.IsSuccess)
  {
    //handle if success
  }
  else
  {
  //handle if failed
  }
}
```

I migrated the FacebookOAuthClient to FacebookClient and after migrating everything this does not work.

My login code is as follows. I have tried both the old way and the new way, but both are not working. The commented portion is my legacy code that worked for 5.4 Can you please help me see what I am doing wrong?

```
//Dictionary<string, object> pParameters = new Dictionary<string, object> 
//{
// {"response_type", "token"},
// {"display", "touch"},
//};
//if ((extendedPermissions != null) && (extendedPermissions.Length > 0))
//{
// StringBuilder pScope = new StringBuilder();
// pScope.Append(string.Join(",", extendedPermissions));
// pParameters["scope"] = pScope.ToString();
//}
```

this is code added for v6

```
Uri pLoginUrl = m_pClient.GetLoginUrl(new { response_type = "token", display = "touch", scope = "publish_stream, offline_access", next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" }); //also tried redirect_uri=""
m_pBrowser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
m_pBrowser.Navigate(pLoginUrl);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you look at the winforms sample at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms-sample

```
    private Uri GenerateLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.client_id = appId;
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

        // The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
        parameters.response_type = "token";

        // list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
        parameters.display = "popup";

        // add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
            parameters.scope = extendedPermissions;
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        // when the Form is loaded navigate to the login url.
        return fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }
```

Comment: I've rolled back my code to version 5.4 as everything is working properly and as expected in that release. I'll wait until v6 is out of alpha.