# How to login to Facebook without a login dialog in C#

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the some WinForm client sample from [Problems when migrating from Facebook SDK v5.4 to alpha v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447482/problems-when-migrating-from-facebook-sdk-v5-4-to-alpha-v6)

to see how I can login into Facebook.

My question: Is it possible to login into Facebook without ANY dialog?

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // open the Facebook Login Dialog and ask for user permissions.
            var fbLoginDlg = new FacebookLoginDialog(AppId, ExtendedPermissions);
            fbLoginDlg.ShowDialog();

            // The user has taken action, either allowed/denied or cancelled the authorization,
            // which can be known by looking at the dialogs FacebookOAuthResult property.
            // Depending on the result take appropriate actions.
            TakeLoggedInAction(fbLoginDlg.FacebookOAuthResult);
        }
```

Comment: @MerickOWA I used http://csharpsdk.org/

Comment: Are you talking about an automatic log in? So you open the form, and it immediately logs into facebook without requesting any user input? In that case you would need to do it similar to a browser. Store the login data and automatically input it when the form opens. How to do this? no idea

Comment: @Tony318 "an automatic log in?" yes yes exactly  I have to implement some DLL which will get some data from Facebook I don't need any dialog/popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not allowed to store user login/password in the database and use it for "automatic" login - as per [Facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> I. Features and Functionality
>
> ...
>
> 3 -  You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects Facebook usernames or passwords.

therefore the answer is - NO, you cannot do that, and you are not allowed to do that.

Comment: So no chance to exclude WebBroswer Control ? So I always have to login via WebBrowser control?

Comment: Is there way to get Facebook Wall feed/posts without login then?

Comment: you can get get access token for yourself, hardcode it in your application and then call https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN - you will get public posts for Coca Cola. Or insert any other user ID - you will get his/her public feeds as well.

Comment: Cool!! Could u suggest any sample Windows project which represent Facebook public Wall posts, please? I really cannot find any example how to get feed and bind it to WPF user controls so to have all Wall within a desktop WPF app...

Comment: @avs099 I think that would only work for at most 60 days before the access_token would become invalid

Comment: @MerickOWA so token expires after 60 days? Where do I can generate it?

Comment: Yes graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN  works great for the TOKEN. But which link I have to use to get any public Wall feed? Can you suggest it please?

Comment: what do you mean by "any"? :) you need to insert facebook user ID instead of "cocacola". Open FB page of any of your friends - URL will be https://www.facebook.com/<<FRIEND_NAME>> - so use that friend name instead of cocacola

Comment: @Peretz "However, there is no way to get a long-lived user access_token without having the user login to your app again."  See http://bit.ly/LH4plW

Comment: @MerickOWA I found it under the Facebook link &expires_in=6160  What does it means? Days? Could you clarify it pls!!

Comment: @MerickOWA - i think it's possible to use application access token (which never expires) to query the feed. I'm not sure if you get the same data - I would say if it's public then the app should get it as well. See here how to get app token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: @Peretz - expires is in seconds. You can extend it for 60 days as described here (see section 4): https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: @Peretz - Check the documentation for the SDK it explains what values `expires_in` accepts.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea and it wouldn't fit in the comment box.

So you'll need the user to initially input their data. Storing it in a database or file somewhere on the server so that it is accessable. I'd say the best way to go about it is for first time visitors to have them log in and then prompt if they would like to save crednetials or whatever. If yes then it would take their username and password as well as say their windows login and encrypt them and store them in a database. Now, when a user uses the WinForm, it would need to first check their windows login using windows authentication. After finding their login name you would go through your data and find their login then pull their username and password, automatically populate the field and log in.

Try implementing something similar to that.

Comment: nope - read my answer please. What you are suggesting is against FB policy.

Comment: I was in the middle of my response when you posted. How do facebook apps and such get away with it? I guess it doesn't go against FB policy if the data is stored as a cookie? Or do most applications that allow facebook login just break that policy?

Comment: they use tokens - which require prior authorization usign FB login dialog.

Comment: So they allow the use of tokens with authorization but not storing the data in a database with authorization.